# JBuilder call to_builder from views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

I like the idea of defining a `to_builder` method for each model and using that in the views. However, when I call it from a view, it returns a string instead of an object. How can I use a generic to_builder method in the view and return an object instead of using `instance.(self, *self.attributes.keys)` in the view?

```
 # doctor should be an object, not a string representation of the object
 resp = [id: 1, content: "content", doctor: "{"id":245}" ]

  def to_builder
    Jbuilder.new do |instance|
      instance.(self, *self.attributes.keys)
    end
  end

json.medical_relationships @medical_relationships do |rel|
  json.(rel, *rel.attributes.keys)
  json.patient rel.patient_profile.to_builder.target!
  json.doctor rel.doctor_profile.to_builder.target!
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `merge!`:

```
json.merge! rel.patient_profile.to_builder.attributes!
```

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27335069/1319954